# Splitting 2 JSON file data

Tags: javascript, json

I read 2 different JSON file and putting inside in a array. I did it but now I want to split them. I tried almost everything but code thinks the array is 1 piece and doesnt split.

JavaScript Putting Array Code;

```js
fs.readdir("./bilgiler/kisi-bilgiler/", async (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(f => {
    dosya.bilgi.push(fs.readFileSync(`./bilgiler/kisi-bilgiler/${f}`, {}))
  });
  dosya.sayi = files.length;
  console.log(dosya.sayi)
});
```

Json data's

```json
{
"kisisel_bilgiler": {
            "isim": "Theredorfin",
            "soyisim": "Endorfinoglu"
       }
}
,
{
    "kisisel_bilgiler": {
        "isim": "Muhammet",
        "soyisim": "Temi"
    }
}
```

The code I want to seperate and create divs for each data;

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            let kisiler = JSON.stringify({{{veri.bilgi}})
            let sonVeri = JSON.parse(kisiler) // Final Data


            for (var i = 0; i < {{veri.sayi}}; i++) {
                console.log(({{{veri.bilgi}}}).lenght)
                $(".kisiler").append(`
                <div class="kisiKutu">
                <h3>${sonVeri[i].kisisel_bilgiler.isim}</h3>
                <p>${sonVeri[i].kisisel_bilgiler.soyadi}</p><br />
                </div>`);   
        }
    });
```

Express Code which I publish the Page;

```js
app.get("/bilgiler/kisi-liste", (req, res) => {
  res.render("kisi_bilgi/kisiler_liste", {
   veri: dosya
  })
})
```

Comment: Your JSON object has two identical keys. When you try to find an item on `sonVeri[i].kisisel_bilgiler` which one do you expect it to get?  You won't be able to tell them apart.  You might need to use `Object.entries()` or `Object.values` to iterate the items in your JSON